# How to add indentation in code in markup list

Tags: markdown, markup, readme

I am writing steps to perform action, one of which require execution of code. How can I indent code to same level as list

1. Execute step 1
2. Execute code from block2

```
# This should be starting from Just below `Execute code from block2 not from beginning of line`
```

3. Execute step 3

Comment: This is actually markdown engine specific, but have you tried adding 4 spaces in front of the code block?

Comment: @Simone Thanks apparently it's working with new UI.